# when I compile this code I get error like Integer number too large. Though I declare it as long, I don't know why it is showing error?

Tags: java

why I am getting error integer too large. As I declare it as long.
Here is my code

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    long x=sc.nextLong();    
    if(x>=-9223372036854775807 && x<=9223372036854775806)
    System.out.println("long");
```

Answer (score 6):

Put an "L" at the end of your numbers:

```
if(x>=-9223372036854775807L && x<=9223372036854775806L) System.out.println("long");
```

Such that the compiler sees them as longs, not ints.

Comment: If you want to be really spiffy you could put underscores in them as thousands separators to make them easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

By default all constant numbers all `int`, so you need to put `L` at the end of your numbers: `9223372036854775806L`
But, the better way is using `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MIN_VALUE` instead of hard coding those large numbers.

Comment: I didn't recognize those constants as being min/max of long. Good observation. Now I would ask OP what value of `long x` would fall outside that range??? That `if` statement can't ever be false.

Comment: Yes, x is always a long value

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting this error because of your `x` variable you are getting it because of number `literals` `-9223372036854775807` and `9223372036854775806`.

Because by default number literals are treated as `int` and you need to append an extra `L` at end of them to tell compiler to treat them as `long literal`.

How ever you should use `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MIN_VALUE` constants for this comparison. If your max and min value varies from the Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE, it is a best practice to create `constants` for them and then use them e.g.

```
final static long MIN_VALUE = 100000L;
final static long MAX_VALUE = 10000000L;

if(x<MIN_VALUE && x>MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("This is an invalid value");
```